# Why is my parameter not defined in Fast Reports?

Tags: parameters, fastreport

I am very new to Fast Reports, and I am trying to define a variable which is a repeated column value in a table, so that it may only be rendered once.

I thought that the way to accomplish this is to define it in the 'Parameters'.

In the image you can see my settings of the parameter and the syntax for calling it:

[image]

I am getting the error message `Text15: Error CS0117: FastReport.Data.Parameter doesn't contain a definition for Customer` (*the message copy is translated from Swedish - though I expect the English error message is close to this*)

Answer (score 0):

I was so far off the mark it was hilarious - and a little sad.

Found the GUI for adding page and or group headers, which programmatically renders a value only once.

Hope no one wasted any time on this.